# Angularjs, Applying Action on Selected Checkboxes in Table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im trying to Learn AngularJS and im implementing this Checkboxes that when i some checkboxes from the Grid and click the Remove Button then the Data from Table Should Be removed of Selected CheckBoxes.

I tried but cant figure out how to implement it.

Please see my this code on Plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/e7r65Me4E7OIWZ032qKM?p=preview

It would be nice, if you fork and Give Working Example of the Above Plunker.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An easy way would be to change your students list to:

```
$scope.students = [
  {Rollno: "1122",Name: "abc",Uni: "res", selected: false},
  {Rollno: "2233",Name: "def",Uni: "tuv", selected: false},
  {Rollno: "3344",Name: "ghi",Uni: "wxy", selected: false}
];
```

with:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.selected">
```

in the view. With injecting [`filter`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) into the controller, you can then rewrite the *remove* function to:

```
$scope.remove = function(){
  $scope.students = filterFilter($scope.students, function (student) {
    return !student.selected;
  });
};
```

here is full code:

```js
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('TableCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', function($scope, filterFilter) {
    $scope.students = [
      {Rollno: "1122",Name: "abc",Uni: "res", selected: false},
      {Rollno: "2233",Name: "def",Uni: "tuv", selected: false},
      {Rollno: "3344",Name: "ghi",Uni: "wxy", selected: false}
    ];

    $scope.save = function(){
      $scope.students.push({
        Rollno: $scope.new_rollno,
        Name: $scope.new_name,
        Uni: $scope.new_uni
      });

      $scope.new_rollno = $scope.new_name = $scope.new_uni = '';
    };

    $scope.remove = function(){
      $scope.students = filterFilter($scope.students, function (student) {
        return !student.selected;
      });
    };
  }]);
}(angular.module('app', []), angular));
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

table
{
  width: 100%;

}
table,th,td
{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.color
{
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.color2
{
  background-color: white;
}
#heading
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
tr:hover
{

  background-color:darkblue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#images img
{

  margin-top: 10px;
}
#img1
{
  width: 33.4%;
}
#img2
{
  width: 66%;
  height: 255px;
}
#table1
{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
label
{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
button
{
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <label>Search:</label>
      <input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Enter to Search">
    </div>

    <div id="table1" ng-controller="TableCtrl">
      <table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr id="heading">
          <th>Roll NO:</th>
          <th>Student Name:</th>
          <th>University:</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="color2" ng-repeat="student in students | filter:search | filter:new_search">
          <td>{{student.Rollno}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.selected"> </td>
          <td>{{student.Name}}</td>
          <td>{{student.Uni}} <button ng-click="remove($index)">x </button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <div>
        <label>Rollno:</label>
        <input type="number" ng-model="new_rollno"> <br>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="new_name"><br>
        <label>University:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="new_uni"><br>
        <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
      </div>

      <div style="float: right; margin-right: 300px;margin-top: -200px;">
        <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yoshi your solution seems to be perfect but it is better of not assign $scope.students to a new value in remove function because then it will recreate all the ng-repeat elements from scratch so it is better of just splicing the elements from students array to avoid recreating ng-repeat all over again.

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal
Please Can you Explain How to do this with Splice in other Answer?

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal You're right. Tough personally I would first wait for the redraw to become a real problem (as this greatly depends on the amount of data). Until then, I would use `filter` for it's *self-descriptiveness* alone.

Comment: Also, with the new v1.2 feature of [`track by`](http://youtu.be/W13qDdJDHp8?t=20m17s), the whole problem of redrawing all entries should become obsolete.