# angularjs remove Selected Items using splice Function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was looking for a solution to remove items from the Grid; that's why I posted the question before. But when I got the solution from someone, at that time, I thought it solved the issue, but it was using a Filter method.

However, I want the items to be removed from the GRID using a Splice Function.

Here is my old Question Link
[Angularjs, Applying Action on Selected Checkboxes in Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358954/angularjs-applying-action-on-selected-checkboxes-in-table)

I want it to execute using a Splice Function.

Right now the problem I am facing is to pass the index value to the function so that the item can be deleted if that index value is selected/fetched. I am not sure how to fix it.

It would be nice if someone solves the problem and gives a demo link to the updated code.

Here is the Plunker Link for what I have tried so far.[Plunker link to show my execution](http://plunkr.co/edit/e7r65Me4E7OIWZ032qKM?p=preview)

Comment: kindly see below plunker demo for splice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added ng-click to checkbox to make it working

http://plnkr.co/edit/DSVPj3holsf4nhNvEMbQ?p=preview

Comment: Thankyou for Reply,
Your Code Works Great for the First Time, But next time when i select a check box it removes 2 values?

Comment: i mean first time i load page -> i select checkbox then i click remove, item removes, but without refreshing page when i click the other checkbox and i click remove it remove 2 items.

Answer (score 7):

Definition of JS array.splice method (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)):

> array.splice(index , howMany[, element1[, ...[, elementN]]])

So, your `remove`function should be written as:

```
$scope.remove = function(index){
  $scope.students.splice(index, 1);
};
```

[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/SHrL9NcmG5K7qe1u9NeI?p=preview)

**EDIT:**

I figured you wanted to remove the items by clicking the "x" button with ng-click pointing to `remove` function.

To remove the items by clicking the checkbox you should set checkbox ngModel to a student property and than put a $watcher on students that would remove those students who have this property set to true:

```html
<tr class="color2" ng-repeat="student in students | filter:search | filter:new_search">
  <td>{{student.Rollno}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.checked"> </td>
  <td>{{student.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{student.Uni}} <button ng-click="remove($index)">x </button></td>
</tr>
```

```js
$scope.$watch('students', function(students){
   if(!students){
     return;
   }
  $scope.students = students.filter(function(student){
    return !student.checked;
  });
}, true);
```

[PLNUKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/bVjVpPpz5o0ER5koIaiW?p=preview)

Comment: already have done that, but this dont remove the selected items from the Grid.

Comment: The plunker link that I attached proves otherwise.

Comment: Sir, i have checked your Demo Plunker link, i cliked on first check box and on the last one but it removed only 1 item from the grid.